# Deleting row from database does not work

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, http-post

I'm trying to make a function that would delete from a mysql database
a record from a specific table specified by the user and the row which
will be used in the WHERE clause depends on the table chose.

This is what I have:

```
 $table=$_POST['table'];
 $title=$_POST['title'];
 if($table=="clients")
     $row="fullname";
 else if($table=="books")
     $row="title";
 else if($table="actors")
     $row="fullname";
 else if($table="employees")
     $row="fullname";

 $result = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE from $table WHERE $row='{$title}'") or die (mysqli_error($con));

 if($result) {
     $_SESSION['updateinfo']='deleted';
     header("location:index.php");
 } else {
    $_SESSION['updateinfo']='not deleted!';
    header("location:index.php");
 }
```

Well, it works fine when I try to delete from clients,books,actors, but it does not work for employees.

I get the message " deleted ", but its still there.No error, no nothing. 
Also I would have to add 10 more those tables, is there a better way to do this?

**I tried to echo $table, $title and $row and it seems that the SELECT from the HTML form only passes to the PHP script the correct value for the first 3 options, for the rest of them it passes a wrong value, below is my html form**

```
 <select name="table" style="padding:5px;margin:5px;width:200px;">
  <option value="clients" selected="selected">Clients</option>
  <option value="books">Books</option>
  <option value="actors">Actors</option>
  <option value="employees">Em</option>
  <option value="other1">smthother</option>
  <option value="other2">smtoher2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: trim title and are you sure the column name in employees table is fullname?

Comment: debug/print the query for employee table....and better go for `switch` case instead of multiple `if else if { }`

Comment: You need to debug your solution, var_dump, or log your query (or add to success notification) to check,  mysqli_affected_rows() will show number of deleted rows, seems you just have no match, trim your input values...

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for fast reply, I found out something.So I tried to echo $table, $title and $row and for some reason for some options from the select form is always the same value passed to the php script.   When you choose employee from the select form, it passes the value actors

Comment: WARNING: SQL injection! I hope you will not use this in prod. mode, since its vulnerable to SQL injection. Sanitise the data with *mysql_real_escape_string*